# How to pass password to a password input?

Tags: bash

For example, I need to connect to a rpcclient which have the password of `admin`.
Basically I want to connect to the server with a single line, e.g:

```
echo 'admin' | rpcclient -U '' x.x.x.x
```

when I do above, I get:

```
root@kali:/home# echo 'admin' | rpcclient -U '' x.x.x.x
Enter WORKGROUP\'s password: 

root@kali:/home#
```

Notice, there is no rpcclient connection established, but if I do this manually It works just fine, see below:

```
root@kali:/home# rpcclient -U '' x.x.x.x
Enter WORKGROUP\'s password: 
rpcclient $>
```

Comment: If you are really serious about security: stop using a root prompt, use sudo with a decent password.

Comment: @rinzwind he is using kali linux, it runs the desktop with root

Comment: @cmak.fr no it does not. Kali is not a desktop install. It is a live session install.

Comment: it is live or install, op can choose. fortunately. And in both cases, session is root since sec tools need all privileges

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the man page of rpcclient](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/rpcclient.1.html)

```
rpcclient [-A authfile] [-c <command string>] [-d debuglevel] [-l logdir] [-N] [-s <smb config file>] [-U username[%password]] [-W workgroup] [-I destinationIP] {server}
```

You may use the `-A` option with a credentials file or the complete `-U` option
`-A|--authentication-file=filename`
`-U|--user=username[%password]` `-W workgroup`

The credentials file looks like this

> username = [value]
>   password = [value]
>   domain   = [value]

```
rpcclient -A /path/to/cred.file xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
rpcclient -U "login%password" -W "domainname" xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Comment: see below comment on rinzwind's post.

Comment: @setayesh probably domain that cant be empty, try with `-U '%admin'` OR if you are using a computer account, its different...

Answer (score 1):

> Notice, there is no rpcclient connection established, but if I do this manually It works just fine, see below:

That is by design.

[From the manual](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/rpcclient.1.html):

```
-A | --authentication-file=filename

This option allows you to specify a file from which to read the username 
and password used in the connection. The format of the file is

username = <value>
password = <value>
domain   = <value>

Make certain that the permissions on the file restrict access 
from unwanted users.
```

Comment: I just tried this, but says permission denined: `# cat creds 
username = ''
password = admin
domain   = ''` and then `# rpcclient -A ./creds x.x.x.x` but I get: `Cannot connect to server.  Error was NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED` but tried the sam creds manually it works